# How to remove this green highlighted color in wsl terminal in vs code

Tags: visual-studio

I want to remove green highlighted colour.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing the permissions on the folder with `chmod 0775 -R 'New folder'` removes the Green highlighted color with default color settings